# How to fix output framerate in playbin?

Tags: c, gstreamer, frame-rate

What I need is to use `gstream` playbin to play the video at a different frame rate than the original video framerate.
For example, the actual framerate of a video recorded with the camera's 30 fps setting is 30000/1001, but I would like to force play to 30 fps.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v playbin uri=http://media.w3.org/2010/05/video/movie_300.mp4 video-sink="videorate ! capsfilter caps=video/x-raw,framerate=3000/1000 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink"
```

I tried above thing and i can see internal framerate of videorate element path is changed to "framerate=(fraction)3/1"
But remaining elements are still keep original framerate after videorate.

Is there a way to reset the caps of all paths or to override the framerate value of the original source when parsing?

Comment: Your sample works correct. It plays a 30 fps video as 3 fps for me. Read on however what `videorate` exactly does. It repeats or throws away frames. It does not do a frame rate conversion. So you cannot fix sync issues that way.

Comment: I would like to control final output framerate rather than filtering by dropping or duplicating frames to achieve the given rate.